# Azure check-in from Visual Studios 2015

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015

So I'm attempting to check in from visual studios to deploy my code to an azure web app, however I cannot for the life of me find the check in option. I'm connected to the Visual Studios Online repo and can view the web app in the server explorer. Googling this has found me nothing so either this is a clearly labeled feature I'm blind to or support for the feature has been dropped from visual studios and everyone simply knows this.

Comment: Do you want to publish the site directly to Azure from within **Visual Studio**, or are you after automated deployment from **Visual Studio Online** after you have checked in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build-in build step in **Visual Studio Online**: *Azure Web App Deployement*.

1. In your build definition click on ***Add Build Step***
2. In *Deploy* Category you will found the step: ***Azure Web App Deployement***
3. Click ***Add***

In **Visual Studio 2015**, you must do a power Shell script to deploy it.

You can find more information at this address:

- [Web Deploy command line](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#webdeploy)
- [Deploy with PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-deploy/#deploy-with-powershell)

Comment: If you want **continuous integration**, don't forget to check the **option in triggers**

Comment: I followed the Deploy with PowerShell link but I don't have Azure Powershell so I quickly googled it, I found this:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/

Which tells you to run the Microsoft Web Platform Installer which results in the error: 

The Web Platform Installer could not start. Please report the following error on the Web Platform Installer forum. http://forums.iis.net/1155.aspx

I get this error when I'm trying to upgrade Microsoft Azure SDK from 2.7 to 2.7.1 on Visual Studios.

Comment: Try to install/reinstall the webPI: [http://forums.iis.net/t/1178551.aspx](http://forums.iis.net/t/1178551.aspx)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Still throwing the same error, I ran repair and a full uninstall/reinstall. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Wich version of visual studio are you using ?